# How append a string at the end of all lines?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, parsing

I'm trying to add a string at the end of all lines in a text file, but I have a mistake somewhere.

Example:

I've this in a text file:

```
begin--fr.a2dfp.net
begin--m.fr.a2dfp.net
begin--mfr.a2dfp.net
begin--ad.a8.net
begin--asy.a8ww.net
begin--abcstats.com
...
```

I run:

```
sed -i "s|\x0D$|--end|" file.txt
```

And I get:

```
begin--fr.a2dfp.net--end
begin--m.fr.a2dfp.net--end
begin--mfr.a2dfp.net--end
begin--ad.a8.net
begin--asy.a8ww.net--end
begin--abcstats.com
...
```

The string is added only in certain lines and not in others.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\x0D` is carriage return, which may or may not be visible in your text editor. So if you've edited the file in both Windows and a Unix/Linux system there may be a mix of newlines. If you want to remove carriage returns reliably you should use `dos2unix`. If you really want to add text to the end of the line just use `sed -i "s|$|--end|" file.txt`.

Comment: Yes, it's a text file from Windows edited in Linux.
`dos2unix` really solve problem and now, add `--end` at the end of all my lines.
Thank You!!!!

Comment: @user294721 if this answer solves your problem, please remember to mrk it as accepted.

Comment: you can remove the carriage returns in the same sed: `sed 's/\r\?$/--end/'`

Answer (score 4):

There are may ways of doing this:

1. Perl

   ```
   perl -i -pe 's/$/--end/' file.txt
   ```
2. sed

   ```
   sed -i 's/$/--end/' file.txt
   ```
3. awk

   ```
   awk '{$NF=$NF"--end"; print}' file.txt > foo && mv foo file.txt
   ```
4. shell

   ```
   while IFS= read -r l; do 
    echo "$l""--end"; 
   done < file.txt > foo && mv foo file.txt
   ```

Comment: @user294721 you're very welcome. Please remember to [accept](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) one of these answers so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using [`ex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor)):

```
ex +"%s/$/--end/g" -cwq foo.txt
```

which is equivalent to `vi -e`.

Option `-i` isn't quite compatible between Linux and Unix and it may not be available on other operating systems.